# Weird Arm LSL Instruction

Tags: syntax, arm

While looking some arm stuff in ida i came across this code

```
LSLS R3, R1
```

I know this is the left shift instruction but according to the [arm website](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/BABDJCHA.html) it should have Rs or #sh after it.

What does this mean? Is it just `LSLS R3, R1, #0`?

Comment: when you assembled it and then disasembled it what did you find?

Comment: gnu assembler gives this which makes sense...e1b03113 lsls r3,r3 r1 they tend to allow that since the thumb instructions are often two register, they let you be lazy.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a shortcut for:

```
LSLS r3, r3, r1
```

This is because in Thumb, the destination and first source registers need to be the same for most instructions.

Answer (score 0):

in Thumb, LSL(S) third operand can't be #0.

Restrictions in Thumb code
Thumb instructions must not use PC or SP.
You cannot specify zero for the value in an LSL instruction in an IT block.sh
https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/m/arm-and-thumb-instructions/lsl?lang=en